# Hibernate: query by example and many to one to create lists

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Let's say those are my Entity:

Product.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
public class Product{
    private int code; 
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private byte[] image;
    private String image1;
    // For sort.
    private Date createDate;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoryId")
    private Category category;
}
```

Category.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Categorys")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int categoryId;
    private String categoryName;
    private String categoryUrl;
    @Column(name = "categoryStatus", length = 1, nullable = false)
    private boolean categoryStatus;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "categoryId")
    private List<Product> listProduct;
}
```

I want to list all rows Products by category id. but I don't know how to query by Hibernate
Here's an example tool that I'm working on but it doesn't work.
someone please help me

```
@Override
public List<Product> getListByCategory(int categoryId) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("FROM product WHERE categoryId = categoryId");
    query.setLong("categoryId", categoryId);
    List<Product> list = query.list();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: `FROM product WHERE category.categoryId=:categoryId` should work. Notice the additional refernce to `category` (the name of the attribute in `Product`) and an additional `:` to note the name of the parameter. All of this is also covered in a basic HQL query tutorial, so you might want to read -up on that.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
FROM product p WHERE p.category.categoryId = :categoryId
```